# pay with paypal details without redirecting to paypal site

Tags: paypal, payment

Can I make payment with paypal details using paypal id and password without redirecting to paypal site? I want to do all payment process without leaving my website.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can by using [PayFlow](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway) but the point of redirecting to paypal is to make sure the payment is secure, not doing so might put your customers off and you'll have to focus time on locking down your payment page.

1. [Payflow overview](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro)
2. [Full payflow developer guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf).