# Automatically click a link on the next 3rd party page

Tags: paypal

I am using a paypal donattion button on my website:
http://naturalistevmr.com/index.php/donate

Once I click that paypal button, it redirects to paypals donation website.
This website is very confusing for my donors as they would just like to pay with credit card, and you have to click the small text "Continue" to open the credit card fields.

Is it possible to create a script which automatically clicks the "continue" link on the paypal page, after the donate link has been clicked on my original page?

Any info is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Surely you can't do that ... Paypal wouldn't be very secure if you could automatically click buttons for the user. I think you need to approach the problem a different way.

Comment: Here's a possible solution is to integrate the payment in your site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494439/pay-with-paypal-details-without-redirecting-to-paypal-site
Personally I think the paypal interface is good because it assures me that the website isn't trying to do anything dodgy with my credit card details, and that the connection is secure. It's the same for whatever site I visit, which is a good thing.

Comment: Clickjacking much? Also, I am more than surprised at the implicit criticism of PayPal's payment workflow... you know, *only the thing they built a billion-dollar business doing well*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I appreciate it.

Oddly enough, Internet Explorer/Edge goes straight to credit card details page, without having to click Continue like Chrome.

I like the paypal interface, and the assurance it's secure. But the tiny text of "continue" to enter credit card details is hard to find, and unfortunately donors are easily demotivated and we loose out for our volunteering efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the PayPal option out of the picture and only offer direct credit cards, you would need PayPal Pro. For more information on Pro and signing up, you can go to www.paypal.com/pro.