# Paypal payment in the background using API call in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I was desperately trying to implement the **paypal** payment in my website without actually redirecting to paypal's website. I need to stay on my website and send the card and personal details to the paypal and receive the response. I read some the documents in the paypal's site like **adaptive payment** etc. But it only left me more confused and are less informative for me. Is there actually any way to do it? can someone shed some light on this..?

Comment: Have a look on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494439/pay-with-paypal-details-without-redirecting-to-paypal-site

Comment: Look into using either Payments Pro or Payflow.